# How do you install zlib on aarch64?

Tags: zlib

I'm trying to see if I can get wagtail running locally on my Android phone (aarch64) with Termux. But it uses Pillow which has a dependency for zlib. I can't seem to find zlib on package depos like apt or pkg. Do I need to compile it from source? (Still a novice with Unix, sorry.)

Answer (score 2):

zlib is [already there](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis#zlib) in the NDK.

Comment: How do I use these APIs to use as packages in Termux?

Answer (score 1):

i was having the same problem. i have a note 8(samsung). just go to GitHub and install zlib from there, after that you will be avaible to install pillow.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by running `termux-chroot` before running `buildozer`
buildozer expecte zlib to be
`/usr/include/zlib.h`
but in termux it is in
`$PREFIX/include/zlib.h`
By running `termux-chroot`, $PREFIX will be `/usr`